# How to dynamically change the header title text in a react native app?

Tags: react-native

I have been struggling with something that sounds simple. I have been trying to get button when onpressed is called. Have tried several combinators but nothing works. Any ideas?

```
export default class JobScreen extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
        title: "Chat with"
    });

    onPressLearnMore(nav) {

        // how do I update the title header 

        console.log("On Pressed" + nav)
    }

    render() {
        const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;


        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => {this.onPressLearnMore(navigate)}}
                    title="Learn More"
                    color="#841584"
                />

            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `navigationOptions` has access to the `navigation` object, you can set some param on the current screen with `this.props.navigation.setParam({ title: ‘some title’ })` and then access it in `navigationOptions` like this

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state: { params = {} } } = navigation;
  return {
    title: params.title || ‘default title’,
  };
}
```

Comment: You gotta tell me more for me to help you instead of straight up down voting it lol. Anyway, if you want help, can you provide the error and how are you using the snippet?

Comment: I copy pasted the whole block, and it resulted in syntax errors. Was there something I was supposed to modify in it ?

Comment: This snippet only works in the context of the original question. So unless you provide how exactly you are using it, it’s hard for me to help you

Comment: Even when I take the original code with your snippet and paste it in PHPStorm, I have syntax errors. Right inbetween `const` and `{`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165243/discussion-between-arthur-attout-and-hyb175).